# Multiple errors on typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created the following class in an asp.net core react application:

```
    import * as React from 'react';

    interface MyInputProps {
        inputType: string;
        id: string;
        className: string;
        parentFunction: (string) => void;
    }

    export class LoginInput extends React.Component<MyInputProps, {}> {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        }

        private onChange(e) {
             this.props.parentFunction(e.target.value);
        }

        public render() {
            return <input type={this.props.inputType} id={this.props.id} className={this.props.className} placeholder="username" onChange={this.onChange} />;
        }
    }
```

Now I'm getting the following errors:

- (TS) Parameter 'string' implicitly has an 'any' type.
- (TS) Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Can anyone point to me what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

In another solution I have the following class which works fine:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Country from './Country';
    import CountryModel from './models/CountryModel';

    const countriesUri = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;alpha2Code';

    interface Props {
        onChange: (string) => void;
    }

    interface State {
        countries: CountryModel[];
    }

    class CountryList extends React.Component<Props, State> {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.state = {
                countries: []
            };

            this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            this.getCountries();
        }

        private getCountries() {
            //
        }

        private onChange(e) {
            this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
        }

        public render() {
            return <select onChange={this.onChange} ref='countries'>
                {
                    //
                }
            </select>;
        }
    }

    export default CountryList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the types of the variables e.g.

```
interface MyInputProps {
        parentFunction: (string:string) => void;
    }

    private onChange(e:any) {
         this.props.parentFunction(e.target.value);
    }
```

The error message basically means that if you do not define type it will implicitly add a `:any` to it. The reason for the check is the compiler option `noImplicitAny: true` in the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: My issue is that in another solution I got:

         interface Props {
             onChange: (string) => void;
         }

and it works fine. Maybe it's something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: @V.Vouvonikos Yes, as I said. You have to add the type to it e.g. `string:string` - `variableName: variableType`.